# --prod Build giving warnings and deployed app not loading after upgrading to Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

I recently upgraded an existing Angular 6 App to Angular 7. Most of my App was built on Angular 6 and then I upgraded it.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.5.1",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.28.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.1.3"
  }
}
```

And here's the warning that I'm getting when I'm running `ng build --prod`:

```
C:\Development\Angular\MyApp>ng build --prod
Date: 2018-10-24T17:36:28.367Z
Hash: a03e526b7e8175b25c06
Time: 32695ms
chunk {0} 0.cafd68819f30185de9af.js () 74.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} 1.00224f689303f6e8aae8.js () 33.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {2} 2.c9d485747518d5177cf8.js () 29.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {3} 3.e25546a8136eb13e9af3.js () 31.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {4} 4.120580aa06e187956a3a.js () 51.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {5} 5.890208a2f9c910b04821.js () 62.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {6} 6.659eb84df5c798c5ff39.js () 29.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {7} runtime.4ee86023cc00ae14666e.js (runtime) 1.99 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {8} styles.f6067b501f9d2a5208bf.css (styles) 215 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {9} polyfills.644a401562606166b860.js (polyfills) 59.6 kB [initial] [rendered]chunk {10} main.be4cab576441165d61f9.js (main) 1.13 MB [initial] [rendered]
WARNING in ./src/app/tv/components/add-program-card/add-program-card.component.ngfactory.js
31:52-87 "export 'ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_bh' (imported as 'i2') was not found in '@angular/forms'

WARNING in ./src/app/tv/components/edit-program-card/edit-program-card.component.ngfactory.js
31:52-87 "export 'ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_bh' (imported as 'i2') was not found in '@angular/forms'

WARNING in ./src/app/news/components/edit-article-card/edit-article-card.component.ngfactory.js
33:52-87 "export 'ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_bh' (imported as 'i2') was not found in '@angular/forms'

WARNING in ./src/app/news/components/add-news-card/add-news-card.component.ngfactory.js
33:52-87 "export 'ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_bh' (imported as 'i2') was not found in '@angular/forms'

WARNING in ./src/app/team/components/add-player-card/add-player-card.component.ngfactory.js
33:52-87 "export 'ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_bh' (imported as 'i2') was not found in '@angular/forms'

WARNING in ./src/app/team/components/edit-player-card/edit-player-card.component.ngfactory.js
33:52-87 "export 'ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_bh' (imported as 'i2') was not found in '@angular/forms'

WARNING in ./src/app/boutique/components/add-merchandise-card/add-merchandise-card.component.ngfactory.js
39:52-87 "export 'ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_bh' (imported as 'i6') was not found in '@angular/forms'

WARNING in ./src/app/boutique/components/edit-merchandise-card/edit-merchandise-card.component.ngfactory.js
39:52-87 "export 'ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_bh' (imported as 'i6') was not found in '@angular/forms'

WARNING in ./src/app/games/components/edit-game-card/edit-game-card.component.ngfactory.js
45:52-87 "export 'ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_bh' (imported as 'i2') was not found in '@angular/forms'

WARNING in ./src/app/games/components/add-game-card/add-game-card.component.ngfactory.js
45:52-87 "export 'ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_bh' (imported as 'i2') was not found in '@angular/forms'

WARNING in ./src/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.js
49:53-88 "export 'ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_bh' (imported as 'i5') was not found in '@angular/forms'
```

I didn't think much of the warnings initially. But when I tried to navigate to my App that is hosted on Firebase Hosting, my App is not loading and I'm also getting this error on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e is not a constructor
    at main.be4cab576441165d61f9.js:1
    at Xr (main.be4cab576441165d61f9.js:1)
    at main.be4cab576441165d61f9.js:1
    at new t (main.be4cab576441165d61f9.js:1)
    at Object.mi [as createNgModuleRef] (main.be4cab576441165d61f9.js:1)
    at e.create (main.be4cab576441165d61f9.js:1)
    at main.be4cab576441165d61f9.js:1
    at e.invoke (polyfills.644a401562606166b860.js:1)
    at Object.onInvoke (main.be4cab576441165d61f9.js:1)
    at e.invoke (polyfills.644a401562606166b860.js:1)
```

**Things I've tried so far:**

1. Searched for `ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_bh` and found that it was referenced in [`angular/forms-builds/bundles/forms.umd.min.js.map`](https://github.com/angular/forms-builds/blob/master/bundles/forms.umd.min.js.map) and was updated about 20 min. ago but didn't understand what to make of it.
2. A similar issue was found in this **[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/issues/126)**, which points to **[this comment](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/issues/127#issuecomment-315380579)**, but doesn't look related to my error. It suggests that I need to export everything from `src/index.ts` which I don't have as of now.

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to how do I fix this error?

### UPDATE

I created a Custom Form Control Element in my `SharedModule` that implements `ControlValueAccessor`. Here's the template of the same:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, forwardRef, HostBinding, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category-list',
  templateUrl: './category-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category-list.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CategoryListComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CategoryListComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  myControl = new FormControl();
  selectedValue;
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
  question = 'Would you like to add ';
  @Input() options: string[];
  @Output() added = new EventEmitter();

  // Function to call when the option changes.
  onChange(option: string) {

  }

  // Function to call when the input is touched (when the autocomplete is clicked).
  onTouched() {

  }

  get value() {
    return this.selectedValue;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(option => option ? this.filter(option) : this.options.slice())
      );
  }

  optionSelected(option) {
    if (option.value.indexOf(this.question) === 0) {
      const newOption = option.value.substring(this.question.length).split('?')[0];
      this.options.push(newOption);
      this.added.emit(newOption);
      this.myControl.setValue(newOption);
      this.writeValue(newOption);
    } else {
      this.myControl.setValue(option.value);
      this.writeValue(option.value);
    }
  }

  enter() {
    const controlValue = this.myControl.value;
    if (!this.options.some(entry => entry === controlValue)) {
      this.added.emit(controlValue);
      const index = this.options.push(controlValue);
      setTimeout(
        () => {
          this.myControl.setValue(controlValue);
          this.writeValue(controlValue);
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.writeValue(controlValue);
    }
  }

  // Allows Angular to update the model (option).
  // Update the model and changes needed for the view here.
  writeValue(option: string): void {
    console.log(`writeValue called with ${option}`);
    this.selectedValue = option;
    this.myControl.setValue(option);
    this.onChange(option);
  }

  // Allows Angular to register a function to call when the model (rating) changes.
  // Save the function as a property to call later here.
  registerOnChange(fn: (option: string) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  // Allows Angular to register a function to call when the input has been touched.
  // Save the function as a property to call later here.
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  private filter(value: string): string[] {
    let results;
    if (value) {
      results = this.options
        .filter(option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === 0);
      if (results.length < 1) {
        results = [this.question + value + '?'];
      }
    } else {
      results = this.options.slice();
    }
    return results;
  }

}
```

Do these warnings have something to do with this?

Comment: The right direction here is cutting unrelated code step by step to provide minimal reproduction

Comment: @yurzui, didn't quite understand what you're trying to suggest here. I've updated my question BTW. Could you please check if that could be the reason for these warning and hence the issue?

Comment: @yurzui is suggesting creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- or rather cutting out as many pieces of code as you can while still getting the error. The reverse could also be done: removing pieces of code until the error no longer shows up. Either way, this will show you the part of your app that causes the issue. That will make it easier to determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same WARNINGS and ERROR after upgrade from Angular 6 to Angular 7.
I have deleted my **node_modules** folder then **npm install** again.
Now the compilation succeeds without warnings and I have no more the error *"Uncaught TypeError: e is not a constructor"*.

Comment: Works. I should have done this way earlier. Anyway. Thanks a lot for your help :)